# How to create angular project of specific version with any angular cli version?

Tags: angular

How to specify version of angular that should be installed ? Right now it's 4.2.4 with cli version 1.4.10.
I want to create angular 4.4.6 project. Where to find compatibility matrix of angular and angular-cli ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748417/6666348

Answer (score 0):

There is **`no`** compatability matrix. You can defined in **`package.json`** with specific version and do npm install and it will install that version.

Comment: Is there any standard for defining package.json?