# How to create angular v10 project? not version 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to create an angular app with version 10.1.2 stable but when I do the regular procedure (ng new  --) it automatically creates angular project version 7. Please let me know how I create the specific version that is angular 10?

Comment: Run in your cmd ng version and check if you have angular 10 installed. If not, update your version.

Comment: `npx -p @angular/cli@latest ng new ...`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748417/6666348

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $ npm install --global @angular/cli@10

This will install `@angular/cli@10.1.2` as of writing time.

Now to update your current instance:

> $ ng update @angular/cli

Afterwards, to init a project, you can simply:

`$ ng new angular10-project`

and to verify your version:

`$ ng version`

Comment: it's the release candidate. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases

Comment: That shows v11.0.0-next.2 as the Pre-Release, and v10.1.2 as the Latest Release. When I run `npm install --global @angular/cli@latest` it installs @angular/cli@10.1.2. When I run `npm install --global @angular/cli@next` it installs @angular/cli@11.0.0-next.2...

Comment: @HereticMonkey nice catch, just threw a fast eye. Updated the answer accordingly